# cruisecontrol.net email

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

On CruiseControl.net there is a link called “NUnit Details”.   When you click on this it gives a lot of details including  a summary section that looks similar to this…

Summary
Assemblies tested:  2
Tests executed: 56
Passes: 54
Fails:  2
Ignored:    2

I would like the summary emailed to me on every build.   Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the e-mail is configured in the **ccnet.exe.config** or **ccservice.exe.config** (in C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server) if you are running ccnet a service.

I believe the file that you want to include is **tests.xml** as that includes a detailed listing of the nunit test results. Modify the xslFiles section of the configuration file to include this stylesheet. It will look something like this.

```
<!-- Specifies the stylesheets that are used to transform the build results when using the EmailPublisher -->
<xslFiles>
    <file name="xsl\header.xsl"/>
    <file name="xsl\compile.xsl"/>
    ...
    <!-- add tests.xsl here... --> 
    <file name="xsl\tests.xsl"/>
</xslFiles>
```